# WebKit doesn't paint background-color for entire width of final inline list item

Tags: css, list, webkit, background-color

On our website http://www.dimagi.com, the items in the jQuery menu near the top of the screen gain a background-color on hover.  The hover background-color of the rightmost list item ("About Us") is cut off at the very right edge of the text, seemingly only in WebKit (tested Safari and Chrome in Windows XP).

Can anybody see what I might be doing wrong in the CSS?  Or is this some obscure WebKit bug?

Comment: on a side note, on my netbook I run in 1024x600 and I'm getting horizontal scrollbars on your website. Whats the deal with that? When did 1024 become obsolete. Did I miss the memo on that?

Comment: Thanks Alex -- 1024 is of course not obsolete, though I sense that your question was rhetorical. It was an oversight on our part that I'll be sure to correct.

Comment: sorry I was too sarcastic there. Just looking at the issue now in FF and Chrome and can't see what's causing it straight-off, I developed something similar so trying to compare them now.

Comment: I noticed that the About Us anchor tag is the only one with an ID attached to it, is there any JS working on it as well, or any other reason for it?

Comment: Truthfully I don't remember why we threw an ID on it. I took it off and it didn't affect anything. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 0):

The background is getting clipped because you have a block element inside an inline element and the box model works quite differently for the two. If you set the `display` property of `#dropmenu > li` to `inline-block` instead of `inline` it will work, but I don't know how IE handles that. The other option is to set it to `display: block` and float the `li`s. Either way, you'll have to do a little reworking for the menu CSS.

I figured it out by playing around with Chrome's Developer Tools until I got it to look right-ish. If you're not familiar with it, it's a very similar tool to FireBug in Firefox. Invaluable for debugging your CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot Emily. You're right that Internet Explorer is the reason I avoided using `inline-block`. I've kept floating block `li`s as a last resort.

When you say that I have a block element inside an inline element, are you referring to the `ul` s within the `li` s? What I can't figure out is why only the last `li` is affected, when they all have `ul`s in them.

Comment: I am actually referring to the `a` inside the `li`. I always have trouble wrapping my head around the exact difference in inline vs. block rendering, so I can't really explain the why of it to you. There's some info about a hacky way to get inline-block in IE at http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/ but I can't verify it's effectiveness.

Comment: I think `a` is an inline element, isn't it? `display: inline;` is what Chrome's Developer Tools shows for its computed style.

Comment: You are quite right. I thought I saw a `display:block` on the `a` but I guess I'm making it up. Regardless, margin and padding work quite differently for inline elements. There's a reasonably good illustration at http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ that shows how the padding expands around the element without actually affecting layout.